# Can't create migrations with same name even after deleting the file

Tags: php, laravel

```
php artisan make:migration create_batles_table 
Created Migration: 2017_04_01_123218_create_batles_table

php artisan make:migration create_batles_table                                             
  [InvalidArgumentException]                     
  A CreateBatlesTable migration already exists.                                                  

---------------------File deleted by me-----------------------------

php artisan make:migration create_batles_table                                                                                                                     
 [ErrorException]                                                                                          
 include(/home/lubuntu/Desktop/work/git/lara/database/migrations/2017_04_01_123218_create_batles_table.php): fail  
  ed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Now using another name "newbatles" instead of "batles"

```
php artisan make:migration create_newbatles_table 
Created Migration: 2017_04_01_123343_create_newbatles_table

php artisan make:migration create_newbatles_table 
[InvalidArgumentException] 
A CreateNewbatlesTable migration already exists.  

-----------File deleted by me--------------                                       

php artisan make:migration create_newbatles_table                                                                                                                     
[ErrorException]                                                                                                  
include(/home/lubuntu/Desktop/work/git/lara/database/migrations/2017_04_01_123343_create_newbatles_table.php): f  
  ailed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Why I can't recreate migrations with same name in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: did you also deleted from `migrations` table ?

Comment: Delete migration file if it exists, run `composer du` command and try to create migration again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing something in migrations always run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

It will clear all old stuff and run smoothly!

**Update:**

But remember: the table name must be unique inside that database...it's like a name for folder on a hard drive. You can't have more than one table with that specific name!

Comment: composer dump-autoload worked but needs to do again and again when trying to recreate each time.

Comment: Yes because you are using the same name. It creates a cache and it thinks you want to have the same migration....that is how it works..

Comment: But anyway that what you are doing will create the same table....i think this is not good!!! You can't have same table in same database!

Comment: yes. Actually I stumbled upon it while using extra argument --create=battles  kind of genuine concern.

Comment: OK i hope you understand it better now....the table name must be unique inside that database...it's like a name for folder on a hard drive....you can't have more than one table with that specific name!

Comment: Yes I m not that newbie !

Comment: OK, no offense, it's hard to tell if you are newbie or not... i just want to help.